# How to fix "Launch exceeded timeout in CUDA queue copy_from_device (integrator_intersect_shadow)" Cycles Error for Nvidia GPU's

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error, hardware

i keep having blender cycles randomly crashing (stopping during rendering initialization), i'm using blender 3.6.2 with a RTX2070 and Windows11

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips/solutions for these issues, it is most likely linked to a nvidia driver issue:

- Identify the problem with microsoft "Event Viewer" in order to have more of a precise idea with your hardware failure. Search for this program in your search bar, go in "window logs", then "system" and see if you have any kind of Error/Warnings in the "Display" category while running cycles in rendered view. Most likely, you will see some errors in there, for me i had an error with nvidia "nvlddmkm" *"The description for Event ID 0 from source nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer. If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event. The following information was included with the event:  \Device\000000b2 Error occurred on GPUID: 100 The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table"*
- Ensure you have the latest driver from nvidia, you can download them via https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us it is advised to use a "creator" type driver, however, please note that 99% of blender users will be using a "game" driver, so it might be a better idea to use the same driver of the masses instead.
- It can help to clean uninstall your older driver first before installing a new driver, use "DDU" for a clean uninstall https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html (important, run in in SAFE mode).
- You might have some corrupted drivers files from a previous installation failure for example, here's how you can ensure that you don't have any broken files: Search for "Command prompt", run it as administrator, then execute these lines, one by one "dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth", "dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth", "dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup", "sfc /scannow", it might take some time! then restart your computer.
- It might be possible that some leftover installation keys are still left in your registry, use CCleaner to clean your registry from potential drivers leftovers.
- Adding "TdrDelay" in your key registry might help, this will ensure that windows is not shuting down cycles GPU processing for responding too slowly. To do so, search for "Registry Editor", go to this path: "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers", and within this GraphicsDrivers folder, right click in the right area, "New", "DWORD", name it as "TdrDelay", edit it's decimal value to be 30 for example (in seconds, the default value is 2second, which can be too quick for cycles, in some rare cases). Then do the exact same but with the name "TdrDdiDelay" instead. Restart you computer. Please note that this solution, while avoiding to automatically shut down rightful process by your OS too soon, allow errors to freeze your computer longer than expected as well.

Edit, All these didn't fix it! see T110657 https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/110657